# triggering an onclick for shopify without it happening on page load

Tags: shopify

In my liquid template I've tried to create a trigger for a click event but it seems to trigger on page load and causing more product to be added to the cart than is specified.

I admit, I'm new to shopify but can't figure why it would happen on page load...

Comment: Just wrap it inside document ready?

Comment: Yes, I tried that with no joy..very odd behavior indeed..I'm attatching a listener to all the appropriate elements and that's when it gets triggered... tried  e.preventDefault(); and e.stopPropagation(); as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that on this project I had to declare any selector used as a variable first.